# How to Increase Response Time of JSON based API of simpeHTMLDOM parser

Tags: php, ajax, json, parsing

So basically i was using 42matter's google market API to retrieve application information for my website, but after i found the free version only allowed 500 request/day and was for non commercial use only i had to develop my own API. Like any developer i did some R&D and found about scraping and simpleHTML DOM parser, i used it and was successful in getting my requirement done.

But now, i got a major problem, 42matter's api was super fast, i called the api, and got info quickly on my DOM(in 1 sec), but my api is slow, it is processing the same request in 8 or 10 seconds which on the page is visually slow and not attractive.

I tried to remove the overhead and find only the part which i need, still it was consuming alot of time

the code is following:

```
include('../common/simple_html_dom.php');

$appPackageName = $_REQUEST['appPackageName'];

header('Content-Type: application/json');

$html = file_get_html('https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id='.$appPackageName.'');

foreach($html->find('div.id-app-orig-desc') as $e){

    $description = $e->innertext;
}

$appInfo['description'] = $description;

echo json_encode($appInfo);
```

i used for loop instead of foreach, still slow.
i used advancedHTMLDOM parser, still slow.
What has 42matter's.com used in their api thats makes it fast is the real question, and is something which needs to be discussed

Moreover i am not getting a good response from stackoverflow users also. I have read difficult questions than this, the response of users is also slow.

Comment: Maybe your internet just sucks?

Comment: internet is not the problem, i got a dedicated 50MB connection

Comment: I timed it myself, I got 10 seconds with simple and 5 with advanced. Short of implementing a cache, 5 is the best you can hope for.